# How to read desired ranges of rows in a text file and assign the elements of these ranges to different matrixes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file, matrix

I have a text file which has some elements:

```
5
4
4 3 1 4
3 1 2 1
9 8 1 3
4 Inf Inf 4
13 9 Inf 6
1 3
2 3
3 4
4 5
-1 -1
```

I need to create 2 different matrixes with these elements. The first two elements in the first two rows (5 and 4 here) correspond to the size (mxn) of the first matrix (In this example, a 5x4 matrix). 
I should assign the below mxn elements (from row2 to row5, total 20 elements here) into a matrix. 
After that, the remained values until the final row (which has -1 -1) should be assigned to another pxt matrix (In this example, a 4x2 matrix. The row with -1 -1 indicates the end of the line.)

I will use many text files and the numbers of rows and columns of them are different each other (The sizes of matrixes which should be created are different.), so I need to write codes which can run all of the text files. I've tried to write a piece of code but it's results are wrong because there are empty spaces between values and the program suppose these spaces as characters. Also, 13 and Inf have more than one character. Here is my code and the result for the first matrix. 
Also, I need to create a second matrix like I explain, but I don't know how to do that.

```
clear;
clc;
fileID=fopen('1.txt', 'r'); 
nrow = fscanf(fileID,'%d',1);
ncolumn = fscanf(fileID,'%d',1);
maxrix1 = zeros(nrow,ncolumn);

a = 1;
nline = 1;
while ~feof(fileID) && nline<nrow+2
    line = fgetl(fileID); 
    if(nline > 1 && nline<=nrow+2)
        for b = 1:ncolumn
        if ~ischar(line), break, end
            maxrix1(a, b) = str2double(line(b));
        end
        a = a + 1;
    end
    nline = nline + 1;
end

fclose(fileID);
```

Here is the result I've received, but it isn't true because of the empty spaces and elements which have more than one character (Inf and 13)

```
4   NaN 3   NaN
3   NaN 1   NaN
9   NaN 8   NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN
1   3   NaN 9
```

It should be:

```
4 3 1 4
3 1 2 1
9 8 1 3
4 Inf Inf 4
13 9 Inf 6
```

After correct the code for creating matrix1, I need to create matrix2 like that:

```
1 3
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: So the first matrix has explicit size information and the second doesn't, correct?

Comment: In each text file, the number of rows and columns of matrix1 are written in the first two rows. Matrix2 is always 2 columns but the number of rows is different in each text file. For example, in this example it is an 5x2 matrix but in another text file it may be 3x2 or 10x2, etc. Each text file ends the row with -1-1. I need to calculate the number of rows according to this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
M = str2double(fgetl(fid));
N = str2double(fgetl(fid));

matrix1 = NaN(M,N); % initiallize and preallocate
for m = 1:M
    li = fgetl(fid); % read next line
    matrix1(m,:) = str2double(strsplit(li, ' ')); % avoid str2num
end

matrix2 = []; % initiallize. We cannot preallocate
while true % we will exit explicitly with a break statement
    li = fgetl(fid); % read next line. Gives -1 if end of file
    if ~isequal(li, -1)
        matrix2(end+1,:) = str2double(strsplit(li, ' ')); % avoid str2num
    else
        break
    end
end
matrix2(end,:) = []; % remove last row, which contains [-1 -1]

fclose(fid)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.